# Evaluating $\int \tan^{1/3}(\theta) d \theta$

Tags: integration

I know $\int \tan^{1/3}\theta  d \theta$ is a non integrable but wolfram alpha does it easily. And can anyone explain how a fuction is non integrable? My argument is that there has to be a function which represents the area under a graph. It's just that we do not know it. Please shed a bit light on it. Also, how can we solve $\int \tan^{1/3}\theta  d \theta$?

Comment: Do you mean to say that $\theta\mapsto \root 3\of {\tan(\theta)}$ isn't integrable? If so, why do you say that?

Comment: Actually my teacher gave it to me to pass time. When I was unable to do it and gave the same to my friends, they said it is non integrable.

Comment: OK. Please answer my first question

Comment: How do you know your friends are right. 

I mean they are definitely wrong as wolfram alfa is solving it

Comment: Well, as I told you, my friends said so, and they gave me this "non integrable" excuse and I gave the same argument as stated in the question, but I actually have to admit I don't know why it's non integrable.

Comment: @Rohinb97 I'll try to be clearer. In the question you talked about $\int \root 3\of {\tan}$ being non integrable. Do you really mean to ask about this function or do you mean to ask about $\root 3\of {\tan(\theta)}$?

Comment: It is integrable in elementary terms. Not hard to visualize, a whole lot of not fun to type the details.

Comment: @GitGud actually both. I didn't actually get the concept of non integratibility. There has to be a function which defines the area under a graph. We might not know it, but there must be one. Any clarity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $x=\left(\tan\theta\right)^{\frac23}$, then $xdx=\frac23\left(1+x^3\right)\left(\tan\theta\right)^{\frac13}d\theta$, and therefore
$$\int\left(\tan\theta\right)^{\frac13}d\theta=\frac32\int\frac{x\,dx}{x^3+1}.$$
The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 4):

I know a way which can solve such these kinds of integral so examine it for $\sqrt[3]{\tan(x)}$. If you have $$\int\sin^p(x)\cos^q(x)dx$$ where $p,~q$ are rationals so, by taking  $t=\sin(t)$ you'll have $$\int t^p(1-t^2)^{q-1}dt~$$ Now consult [this method](http://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial) (however I think it is an old way) for the latter integral. If the conditions, illustrated in this method, are well satisfied so the integral can be expressed as elementary functions so we can find the anti-derivative. Unless, I think we can not solve the integral by routine approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I will just leave here the exact solution.\begin{align}
\int (\tan x)^\frac13\,dx=&\frac14 \bigg[-2\sqrt{3}  \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}-2(\tan x)^\frac13 \right)-2\sqrt{3}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}+2(\tan x)^\frac13  \right)\\
&-2\log\left(\tan^\frac23x+1\right)+\log\left(\tan^\frac23x -\sqrt{3}(\tan x)^\frac13+1   \right)\\
&\hspace{5mm}+\log\left(\tan^\frac23x+\sqrt{3}(\tan x)^\frac13+1      \right)    \bigg].
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

By enforcing the substitutions $x=\arctan(t)$, then $t=u^3$, we get:

$$ \int\left(\tan x\right)^{1/3}\,dx = \int\frac{t^{1/3} dt}{1+t^2}=\int\frac{3u^3}{1+u^6}\,du $$
and the last integral can be computed through a partial fraction decomposition. We have:
$$ \int\frac{3u^3}{1+u^6}\,du =C+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2u^2-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{1+u^6}{(1+u^2)^3}\right),$$
not that simple.